# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: jax-ws

I am getting this exception while accessing the jax-ws web service from my client.

i have no idea, what is happened?
anyone who have the solution?
thanks you.

Comment: Do you have any additional information that could show you and us, what class definition cannot be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception means that a class that is needed cannot be found. You will see the name of the class in the exception detail.

Classes are loaded from the classpath defined for your application, that might be via a command line parameter *classpath* or CLASSPATH environment variable.

So, determine the class you need, find out where it is - a JAR file or directory - and make sure that the classpath includes that jar file.

Answer (score 0):

sorry all, it was a silly mistake,A basic java rule,that i violated.
I gave the class name in small letter,once i renamed it to Caps case. Every thing worked fine.