# simple JUnit test assertTrue(true) fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, junit4

Why does the following test fail? Shouldn't `assertTrue(true)` always be true?

```
package a.a.a;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.forwardedUrl;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.Timed;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ConfigurationClass.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class JUnitConfigurationClass {

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext wac;
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before(value = "")
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void init() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Stack trace as follows:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.configureWebResources(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:200)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:183)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.SessionCookieConfig
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: Q: Do you think the test is even getting *called*?  Q: What happens if you name your one and only test something besides "init()"?  Q: What IDE are you using to run the test(s)?  Eclipse?

Comment: Post the error message for your failure. Everything else would just be guessing.

Comment: This is in spring. Im using Sprimg mvc 4.2.3. Renaming things didnt seem to help. I also didnt know junit even had a stack trace. Added it to my original post.

Comment: Your classpath appears to be wrong.`javax.servlet` is not in your unit tests runners class path. How are you running the tests?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392105/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: To run the test, i click the drowdown arrow next to the play button, and do Run as JUnit Test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assert has not failed, that would an "AssertError", but your unit test has thrown an exception while running. In this case  a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. This happens when you don't have the class in your classpath. The class missing is `javax.servlet.SessionCookieConfig`. Is the servlet API in your class path?

Comment: Turns out i just had to add   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
   <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  </dependency> to POM.xml. Everything works now!

Answer (score 1):

What is the `@Before` annotation of AspectJ supposed to do? I think  `init()` isn't called before, so the `mockMvc` is not build. You should try the `org.junit.Before` instead.

Another shot: Is it the same behaviour, if you build `mockMvc` by `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup()`? Probably your context isn't set up correctly. `javax.servlet.SessionCookieConfig` doesn't seem to be available at run time, perhaps you should check the dependencies.

Comment: Wow thanks! I didnt even realize i imported the wrong @Before. Sadly this did not help..